Intuitive explanation of Riemann curvature
I am very pleased to write my first question here :) .
I am self-studying Riemannian geometry, and a few weeks ago, while learning about Riemann curvature, I found the definition somewhat confused me:
$$R(X,Y)Z=\nabla_Y\nabla_XZ-\nabla_X\nabla_YZ+\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z.$$
So, I searched for a more intuitive explanation here's the anwser, which I suggest you  read first in order to understand my argument. This answer explains the geometric meaning of the first two terms in the definition of Riemann curvature very well. However, it does not elaborate on the role of the third term in the Riemann curvature. Based on this answer, I have thought about the geometric meaning of the third term in the Riemann curvature on my own, but I am not sure if this interpretation is reasonable. Therefore, I would like to discuss it with everyone here.
We know that the Lie derivative, in a certain sense, characterizes the bending of a vector field. Specifically, it describes the difference between moving a certain distance first along the vector field $Y$ and then along the vector field $X$, versus moving first along the vector field $X$ and then along the vector field  $Y$. However, if we want to obtain the curvature of the surface in the direction determined by the vectors $X(p)$ and $Y(p)$ at the point $p$ , we should eliminate the interference caused by the bending of the vector fields $X$ and $Y$ . Therefore, I think this is the meaning of the last term $\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z=-\nabla_{[Y,X]}Z$ in the Riemann curvature. 
To make my point more intuitive and specific, I have drawn two diagrams to explain my perspective:Figure 1 and Figure 2(It seems that I'm not allowed to embed my pictures here since it's my first question). 
In Figure 1, I demonstrate the case(in a sufficient small time period, of course) when $[X,Y]=0$, which aligns with the explanation I found in that answer. The red and blue dashed lines represent the integral curves of the vector fields $X$ and $Y$, respectively. The solid green arrow represents the vector $Z(x_0)$, while the dark green and light green dashed arrows represent the parallel transport of the vector $Z(x_0)$ along two different paths, with the endpoint being $x_1$.
The black arrow represents the vector obtained by parallel transporting $Z(x_0)$ along the closed path shown in the diagram, returning to the starting point. In effect, this is equivalent to transporting $Z(x_0)$ along the two different paths.
Figure 2 illustrates the general case(in a sufficient small time period), where the third term $\nabla_{[X,Y]}Z$ in the Riemann curvature needs to be considered. In this situation, there is a discrepancy in the movement along the two paths over the same period, preventing the formation of a closed path. This discrepancy arises due to the inherent bending of the vector fields themselves, which needs to be subtracted. Reflected in the figure, we need to continue parallel transporting the vector $Z(x_1)$ along the integral curve of $[X,Y]$ and then calculate the error with $Z(x_2)$. The black dashed lines represent the integral curves of the vector fields. The other markings follow the same rules as in the Figure 1. We can see that, now the integral curves of the vector fields form a closed loop.
Finally, my question is: Is my explanation in Figure 2 and the comments above reasonable? Are there any mistakes in my explanation? I would greatly appreciate your feedback and discussions. Thank you!

I suggest you read first 1, 2, 3 and, if still necessary, trim down your question.

@KurtG. Thank you for your answer! I understand the necessity of the third term for the Riemann curvature to be a tensor. What I actually want to ask is whether the third term represents the exclusion of the influence of the bending of the vector fields from the calculation of the curvature of the manifolds, as I illustrated in Figure 2?
